# I am getting errors in a hangman game using C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to piece together a hangman game for a small project I am doing, but I getting these errors. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction for referencing these errors. I have pointed out the errors I am receiving inside the code. I am relatively new to coding, so forgive me if this seem trivial

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    int t=1;
    while(t>0)
    {
        char c;
        char a[]="hello";
        int wrong=0;
        std::cout<<"guess the word";
        char new[5]={0};<----------------error: Expected unqualified-id 
        int no;
        char letter;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)<---------error: Member reference base type 'char [6]' is not a structure or union
        {
            std::cout<<"x";
        }
        while(wrong<7 && strcmp(new,a)!=0)<---------error: Expected a type
        {
            no=0;
            std::cin>>letter;
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                if(new[i]==letter)<----------------error: Expected a type
                {
                    no=1;
                    std::cout<<"yes"<<std::endl;
                }
            }
            if(no<1)
            {
                std::cout<<"no"<<std::endl;
                wrong++;
                if(wrong==1)
                {
                    std::cout<<" O"<<std::endl;
                }
                if(wrong==2)
                {
                    std::cout<<" O"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<"/"<<std::endl;
                }
                if(wrong==3)
                {
                    std::cout<<" O"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<"/|"<<std::endl;
                }
                if(wrong==4)
                {
                    std::cout<<" O"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<"/|\\"<<std::endl;
                }
                if(wrong==5)
                {
                    std::cout<<" O"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<"/|\\"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<" |"<<std::endl;
                }
                if(wrong==6)
                {
                    std::cout<<" O"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<"/|\\"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<" |"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<"/"<<std::endl;
                }
                if(wrong==7)
                {
                    std::cout<<" O"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<"/|\\"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<" |"<<std::endl;
                    std::cout<<"/ \\"<<std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        if(wrong==7)
        {
            std::cout<<"play again"<<std::endl;
            std::cin>>c;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"Congratulations!!!"<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"play again"<<std::endl;
            std::cin>>c;
        }
        if(c=='y')
        {
            t=1;
        }
        else
        {
            t=0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you're drawing the arm on the left before the chest, it's trivial to simplify your hangman display code: https://ideone.com/Xn9GSC

Answer (score 2):

`char new[5]={0};` is trying to create an array named `new`. However, `new` is a [keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) in c++ and can only be used for the purpose it's reserved for. Name your array something else.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers :

> An identifier can be used to name objects, references, functions, enumerators, types, class members, namespaces, templates, template specializations, parameter packs, goto labels, and other entities, with the following exceptions:
>
> - The identifiers that are keywords cannot be used for other purposes;
> - The identifiers with a double underscore anywhere are reserved;
> - The identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved;
> - The identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace.